# Sort values in a list or array and show first 5 value in a table

Tags: sorting, pine-script

[image]

I need a code on pine script which sort some of values from Max to Min, then show for example first 5 value with related var_names in a table.

I put a simple example of what I need as jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array with a custom function.

Declare a custom object type (e.g. https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort):

```
type typeTest
    string name
    float level
```

Create a sorting function

```
bubbleSort(arr) =>
n = array.size(arr) -1 
for i = 0 to n - 1
    for j = 0 to n-i-1
        if array.get(arr , j).level > array.get(arr , j+1).level
            temp = array.get(arr,j)
            array.set(arr , j , array.get(arr , j + 1))
            array.set(arr , j + 1 , temp)
            

arr
```

this is an example:

```
    array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test1", 1.51))
    array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test2", 2.55))
    array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test3", -6.13))
    array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test4", 9.22))
    array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test5", -3.98))
    
    arrayTestSorted = bubbleSort(arrayTest)
```

if you want to change sorting order, you can modify the comparison operator in the if statement. Instead of >, use < to sort the elements in descending order.

This is entire code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Il mio script")
type typeTest
    string name
    float level

var arrayTest = array.new<typeTest>()


bubbleSort(arr) =>
    n = array.size(arr) -1 
    for i = 0 to n - 1
        for j = 0 to n-i-1
            if array.get(arr , j).level > array.get(arr , j+1).level
                temp = array.get(arr,j)
                array.set(arr , j , array.get(arr , j + 1))
                array.set(arr , j + 1 , temp)
                

    arr

array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test1", 1.51))
array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test2", 2.55))
array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test3", -6.13))
array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test4", 9.22))
array.push(arrayTest, typeTest.new("test5", -3.98))

arrayTestSorted = bubbleSort(arrayTest)

//just for plotting somethin
plot(close)
```

Comment: Hello dear Damiano.thank you very much for your answer. actually i am new in pine script and i got an error on "arr" when i tried to run this code on pine script.i appreciate if i can have  this code which i can see the results to get it better, if it is possible please.Thanks

Comment: @taha I added the entire code in my previous answer.

Comment: Tank you very much. useful recommendation "bubble Sort"